# Lit-Element Not Resizing on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, lit-element, lit-html

I have a canvas element that should be resizing as the window resizes, but for some reason it doesn't change. The element should remain a square, taking up 80% of the view height.

The relevant css looks like this, and the square class works for another element that isn't being updated in css and javascript.

```js
static get styles() {
    return [
      tachyons,
      css`
        .square {
          width: min(50vw, 75vh);
          height: min(50vw, 75vh);
        }`
      ]
}
```

The canvas doesn't update despite the class being recognized by the browser. I'm using Safari for testing (don't ask why).

```js
const karelView = ({ displayAltCanvas, index, indexes, className }) => {
  return html`<div class=${className || '' + ' mt5'}>
    <canvas
      id="canvasAlt"
      class="square ${displayAltCanvas ? 'bg-light-yellow' : 'absolute o-0'}"
    ></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" class="square${displayAltCanvas ? ' dn' : ''}"></canvas>
    <div class="db w-100">
      <input
        class="w-100"
        type="range"
        min="0"
        value=${index ? index() : 0}
        max=${indexes || 0}
        step="1"
        @input=${e => index?.(parseInt(e.target.value))}
      />
    </div>
  </div>`;
};
```

This is where I think the error is coming from. The callback is being fired correctly, but for some reason the resolutions still match even though the window has resized and the css should have updated the clientWidth.

```js
  async handleResize(canvas) {
    canvas ??= this.canvas;
    if (canvas === null) {
      console.warn('null canvas');
      return;
    }
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const resolutionMatch = canvas.width === width && canvas.height === height;
    if (!resolutionMatch) {
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
    }
    const world = this.state || (await this.worlds).currentWorld;
    // this.index !== undefined && this.index(this.index());
    draw(this.canvas, world);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this._resizers = (() => {
      this.handleResize(this.canvas);
      this.handleResize(this.canvasAlt);
    }).bind(this);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._resizers);
  }

  render() {
    return html` ${karelView({
      displayAltCanvas: this.displayAltCanvas,
      index: this.index,
      indexes: this.indexes,
    })}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<canvas>.clientWidth` properly resizes in native code.

So if Lit is flawless, it must be a bug in your code.

Notes:

- The `connectedCallback` will fire multiple times when you move the element in the DOM
- no need for oldskool `bind()` (unless you pass a funtion *reference*)
- No need to declare `async handleResize` (and it is not the cause of your error)

```html
<my-element></my-element>

<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
        .innerHTML = `<b/><style>canvas{width:50vw}</style><canvas></canvas>`;
    }
    query(selector){
      return this.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", evt => this.handleResize(evt) );
      this.handleResize();
    }
    handleResize(evt) {
      let canvas = this.query("canvas");
      this.query("b").innerHTML = canvas.clientWidth + "px";
    }
  })
</script>
```

##### Or:

```html
<my-element></my-element>

<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
        .innerHTML = `<b/><style>canvas{width:50vw}</style><canvas></canvas>`;
      window.addEventListener("resize", evt => {
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("b").innerHTML = 
             this.shadowRoot.querySelector("canvas").clientWidth + "px";
      });
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
    }
  })
</script>
```